# Save data to 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have accelerometer data (x,y,z) which is being updated every 50ms. I need to store 80 values of the data into a 3D numpy array (1, 80, 3). For example:

```
[[[x,y,z] (at 0ms)
  [x,y,z] (at 50ms)
  ...
  [x,y,z]]] (at 4000ms)
```

After getting the first 80 values, I need to update the array with upcoming values, for example:

```
[[[x,y,z] (at 50ms)
  [x,y,z] (at 100ms)
  ...
  [x,y,z]]] (at 4050ms)
```

I'm sure there is a way to update the array without needing to manually write 80 variables to store the data into, but I can't think of it. Would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: Hello, Airidas I would like to know what is the type of data in the input. Is it a np.array, a list or what else?

Comment: I send the values over wifi as a char array and on the receiving end I convert them to float variables:          
   `ax = gauti_duomenys[0]`, same for y and z values.

Comment: append then concatenate the array `np.concatenate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want your array to always be 80 long, so what I would suggest is `roll` the array and then update the last value.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(80*3).reshape(80, 3)
data
>>> array([[  0,   1,   2],
           [  3,   4,   5],
           [  6,   7,   8],
           ...,
           [231, 232, 233],
           [234, 235, 236],
           [237, 238, 239]])

data = np.roll(data, -1, axis=0)
data
>>> array([[  3,   4,   5], # this is second row (index 1) in above array
           [  6,   7,   8], # third row
           [  9,  10,  11], # etc.
           ...,
           [234, 235, 236],
           [237, 238, 239],
           [  0,   1,   2]]) # the first row has been rolled to the last position

# now update last position with new data
data[-1] = [x, y, z] # new xyz data
data
>>> data
>>> array([[  3,   4,   5], 
           [  6,   7,   8],
           [  9,  10,  11],
           ...,
           [234, 235, 236],
           [237, 238, 239],
           [ 76,  76,  76]]) # new data updates in correct position in array
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Just changed `.reshape(80 , 3)` to `.reshape(-1, 80, 3)` , `data[-1] = [x, y, z]` to `data[0][-1] = [x, y, z]` and `data = np.roll(data, -1, axis=0)`  to `data = np.roll(data, -1, axis=1)` and it's working as expected. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use vstack (initializing the array for the first iteration):

```
data=[x,y,x]  # first iteration
data=np.vstack([data,[x,y,z]]) # for the rest

print(data) # you would have a Nx3 array
```

For the update every N seconds it is easier if you use a FIFO or a ring buffer:
https://pypi.org/project/numpy_ringbuffer/